# custom mouse hiding behind objects as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

i have this here http://www.nzombie.eshost.es/ with a custom mouse. It works perfect, only that when it is behind another movie clip it "hides" itself. I don't know what's wrong. Any advice or help with be appreciated. Here's the mouse class:

```
package 
{
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.ui.Mouse;

public class myCursor extends MovieClip
{
    public function myCursor(stage):void
    {
        stop();
        Mouse.hide();
        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onDown);
        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onUp);
        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, onMove);
        addEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, onRemove);
    }
    private function updateCoor(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        x = e.stageX;
        y = e.stageY;
        e.updateAfterEvent();
    }
    private function onDown(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        updateCoor(e);
        gotoAndStop(2);
    }
    private function onUp(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        updateCoor(e);
        gotoAndStop(1);
    }
    private function onMove(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        Mouse.hide();
        updateCoor(e);
    }
    private function onRemove(e:Event):void
    {
        Mouse.show();
        stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onDown);
        stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onUp);
        stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, onMove);
        removeEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, onRemove);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are adding multiple things to the stage at runtime it would be worth overriding addChild so that everything is added at index 1, leaving the cursor (at index 0) always on top.

Something like this:

```
override public function addChild(value:displayObject):void
{
    var index:uint = 1;
    if(value is myCursor){index = 0;}
    addChildAt(value, index);
}
```

Or simply only ever add new display objects using addChildAt(displayObject, 1) and be sure to add your cursor class at 0;

Comment: I almost didn't understand, because I'm still learning but using addChildAt worked. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue lies not in this class, but in the class where you add `myCursor` object.

The buttons might have been added after the cursor & so the cursor lies behind the buttons in the *display list*. Try adding the `myCursor` after the buttons have been added to stage.